# PCB Layout Review

Tags: buck, layout

I just completed a PCB layout for a buck converter, and I would like some feedback on it (layout is my weakest area right now). Please rip it apart :)

Attached are some screenshots, and I can also provide a link to a video where I walkthrough the whole project.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please post a schematic and link datasheets for the main components. U1 at least but preferably Q1, D1, L1, C7, C3.  The loops  look rather large and you should have the ceramic output caps closer than the bulk capacitor C7. If there is an example layout on the U1 datasheet it would be good to follow it as closely as possible.

Comment: I don't see any testability features\

Comment: As Spehro writes, the loops look rather large. Imho, for SMPS, worry about loops first and thermals second. I.e. bunch stuff together as tightly as possible with shortest and widest polys as interconnects as possible. Especially, Q1, L1, D1 and the input and output caps. There are only a few nodes that are an exception to this.